# Цикл foreach внутри массива

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Пробую перебрать вот такой многомерный массив
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот таким кодом

```
    foreach($array[order] as $dataraw) {

$params = array(

'order' => json_encode(array(

'externalId' => $dataraw[status],
'firstName' => $dataraw[customer][given_name],
'phone' => $dataraw[customer][phone],   

'items' => array(

foreach($dataraw[basket] as $raw) {

    array(
"initialPrice" => $raw[basket],
"productName" => $raw[basket],
            )
        )
    )
)
);
}
}
```

Но выбивает такую ошибку, я так понимаю нельзя влаживать цикл foreach таким путем

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ')' in /home/reklam49/imperial-shop.pro/www/retailcrm/index.php on line 29
```

Как правильно построить циклы что бы не было такой ошибки ??

вот таким должен быть конечный результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну так масив завершайте и дальше перебирайте

Comment: нет, он немного отличается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$params = [];

foreach($array[order] as $dataraw) {


    $items = [];

    if (isset($dataraw['basket']) && !empty($dataraw['basket'])) {
        foreach ($dataraw['basket'] as $raw) {
            $items[] = [
                'initialPrice' => $raw[basket],
                'productName' => $raw[basket]
            ];
        }
    }

    $params[] = [
        'order' => json_encode([
            'externalId' => $dataraw['status'],
            'firstName' => $dataraw['customer']['given_name'],
            'phone' => $dataraw['customer']['phone'],
            'items' => $items
        ])
    ];
}
```

Comment: Помогло!!! Спасибо огромное!!